Remove Quotes from Textfile without trimming first and last quote of the line
I use jpl files to assign Data in my DataLake.
In these text files I experience 3rd Quotes in between the original ones that mess up my allocation system.
Bsp:
dok_dat_feld_61[1]="Order **"**3000000005".

I tried a few things like:
$Variable.Replace("`"","")

$v.Trim('"')

I Expected to clean out all Quotes and Replace the originals at the beginning of the Strings but this system was very very slow especially if you have thousands of files.
I also Tried Indexing the Quotes per Line but failed due to me not knowing how to code.

Please Edit your question and update how the actual text looks like. It's unclear if the dot at the end is part of the actual text

can you share what your expected result should look like?

You can try splitting in 3 parts the string and concat it again.
I try this and it works:
# Original string
$stringa = 'odok_dat_feld_61[1]="Order **"**3000000005"'

# Split the string at the second "
$parts = $stringa -split '"', 3

# Reconstruct the string without the second "
$stringa = $parts[0] + '"' + $parts[1] + $parts[2]

# Output the transformed string
Write-Output $stringa

This is my result
Write-Output $stringa
odok_dat_feld_61[1]="Order ****3000000005"

Write-Output $parts
odok_dat_feld_61[1]=
Order **
**3000000005"


This has worked great so far, i had to tweak it a little bit so it would ignore strings that only had 2 " but otherwise great.

Or use something like
# split the string on the '=' equal sign
$left, $right = ('dok_dat_feld_61[1]=   "Order **"**3000000005" ' -split '=',2)
# reconstruct the line
'{0}="{1}"' -f $left, ($right -replace '"+').Trim()

Output
dok_dat_feld_61[1]="Order ****3000000005"


You can use regex to remove it, see https://regex101.com/r/Cul2Vl/1 for details.
$test = 'dok_dat_feld_61[1]="Order **"**3000000005"'
$test -replace '(?<!=)"(?!$)'

If the string was multiline, you could try with the following pattern, see https://regex101.com/r/07HXvl/1 for details.
$test = @'
text text text text
dok_dat_feld_61[1]="Order **"**3000000005"
text text text text
'@

$test -replace '(?<=="[^"]+)(?<!=)"(?!$)'

